# Stackoverflow exception occurring with C++ Codegear not with Visual C++

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, stack-overflow, portability

I have this scenario:

- data management library written in Visual C++ but loaded and used inside C++ program written using Embarcadero CodeGear
- library and functions loaded in program LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress

the issue is the following:

- the library is ok in Visual C++ test environment
- the program is crashing due to stackoverflow exception using the same calling function sequence with same parameters

simplified code for library:

```
struct TmRecordValue
{
    UINT8 RecordValue[128];
};
struct TmRecord{
    TmRecordValue RecordValues[2];
};
struct TmStruct
{
    UINT32 NumberOfRecords;
    TmRecord* Records;
};
void InitializeStruct(TmStruct* pStruct, int pNumberOfRecords)
{
    memset(pStruct, 0, sizeof(TmStruct));
    pStruct->NumberOfRecords = pNumberOfRecords;
    pStruct->Records = new TmRecord[pStruct->NumberOfRecords];
    memset(pStruct->Records, 0, sizeof(TmRecord) * pStruct->NumberOfRecords);
}
void AddRecordToStruct(TmStruct* pStruct, int pRecordIndex, char* pFirstValue, char* pSecondValue)
{
    strcpy_s(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pStruct->Records[pRecordIndex].RecordValues[0].RecordValue), 128, pFirstValue);
    strcpy_s(reinterpret_cast<char*>(pStruct->Records[pRecordIndex].RecordValues[1].RecordValue), 128, pSecondValue);
}
```

simplified code for program:

```
TmStruct *struct1 = new TmStruct();
int RecordsQuantity = 100000;
InitializeStruct(struct1, RecordsQuantity);
for (int i = 0; i < RecordsQuantity; i++)
{
    AddRecordToStruct(struct1, i, "first", "second");
}
```

Comments:

- program running ok for RecordsQuantity = {10, 100, 1000, 10000} but crashing at 100000
- the program is throwing stackoverflow exception on the AddRecordToStruct function
- the program is throwing stackoverflow exception always on a fixed iteration 
  (#62643)
- I see no recursion behavior and no big stack variables (everything dinamically allocated I would say)
- I would go with stack size increase but before I'd like to check the stack size of Visual C++ test environment against the stack size of the actual running program (but I don't know how to get current thread stack size)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Take a closer look at `memset(pStruct->Records, 0, sizeof(TmStruct) * pStruct->NumberOfRecords);` Are you *sure* about using `sizeof(TmStruct)` there?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake writing the simplified code, I have edited the question; btw still having the same issue; thanks for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check calling conventions. Make sure you use `cdecl` everywhere or `stdcall` everywhere.

Because by symptoms it looks like Visual Studio library is `cdecl` but Embarcadero program assumes it to be `stdcall`, so no stack is deallocated neither by library, nor by caller.

Comment: Thanks,
I have checked the calling conventions for Embarcadero compiler and it is set as "C" (i.e. "__cdecl"); for VC++ compiler I have "__cdecl" too.

BUT

adding explicitly the "__cdecl" keyword both in function prototype inside VC++ library header and in program import header, the issue completely disappears, allowing me to reach iteration 100000+.
Actually I don't know why without the explicit "__cdecl" keyword the calling convention was not properly set; the only possible explanation to me is that the import inside Embarcadero program is done through function pointer (not function).

Comment: I don't have recent experience with Embarcadero products, but as far as I remember from my past experience with Borland Delphi 7, the default calling convention is `register` which is similar to Visual Studio `__fastcall`, *but not completely compatible*.

Comment: My opinion is that it is not a good idea to rely on defaults anyway, if you are linking different language modules, rather you need to specify calling convention explicitly. Maybe wrapped with a macro, if different compilers use different keywords for calling conventions.

And sure you should apply this explicit calling convention to function pointers too.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `sizeof(TmStruct)` for a pointer to `TmRecord` with:

```
memset(pStruct->Records, 0, sizeof(TmStruct) * pStruct->NumberOfRecords);
```

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake writing the simplified code, I have edited the question; btw still having the same issue; thanks for now